# Sharepoint Designer - adding the ID field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, id

When viewing the Edit item form on SharePoint it doesn't show the ID field for that record even though I have it showing on the list view. I have gone into SharePoint designer 2013 and can see the code where it shows each field on the form and tried copying that and changing all the relevant bits to 'ID' but that didn't work. does anyone know how to get this additional field added.

Also does anyone know how to make a field read-only on a form via SP designer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, The ID field is SharePoint only

You can't edit it,

You can't set its numbering,

You can't use it in Calculated Columns,

because the ID is created in the database layer after all Formulas are calculated

If you want it displayed on the Edit Form you have to use JavaScript code and extract it from the URL

### Re: Comments

#### Do not use ID

***ID is an internal number SharePoint requires to store data in the SQL server database***

Its best not to teach users (or anyone) about ID, consider it an internal SharePoint number.

Yes, it is part of the URL, because many moons ago that was the only way to reference Web content

Once you start moving content around with workflows or copy/paste/backup/restore you will run in all sorts of trouble when you have used ID to reference content.
Because it will most likely get a different ID number

#### Read-Only Fields

You can make Fields read-only by editting their **ContentTypes** (like everyone learning SharePoint that will keep you busy for at least a month) No shortcuts to be taken their, as messing with ContentTypes can also break functionality if you do not know what you are doing.

See:

- https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-content-types-understand-use-create

Comment: I don't want to do anything with it just show he user which number they are adjusting the form for. I presumed sharepoint designer was a part of sharepoint and therefore it would work together. Another strange thing about sharepoint.                                                     Is there a way to make any field read only on the edit form?

Comment: Updated  answer to answer your questions

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Id field generate by itself so, you don't 
't even edit the Id field. Because SharePoint Id is not editable. I guess I got your question

Comment: I don't want to edit it, just show it